# ArcGIS 10 Search Services

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I am trying to learn more about the new ArcGIS Server Search that comes with ArcGIS 10.

Does anyone know where I can find detailed instructions on how to implement and use this feature?  Specifically, how to build the search index?

Comment: just noticed you had the ags tag. I will edit with links for that also. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ags (Server), adding a [search service](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Search_services/00930000005t000000/).
For some reason the search service is not on this page.

This is somewhat different from the desktop indexing described below. But it may use the same process on the server.

It should be enabled on install of 10.

I turned mine off. It is a great tool but it along with other full time indexing/scanners my cpu was being bogged down.

If I remember correctly you should see a process running named desktopindexingservice. That is the indexer process.

I was getting [this error](http://blogs.esri.com/support/blogs/supportcenter/archive/2010/07/29/desktopindexingservice-exe-error-message-on-arcgis-10-and-windows-7.aspx) there seems to be a new workdaround for it so I may investigate and turn it back on.

Here is more info from the webhelp on resources.arcgis.com
[Web Help online](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#/Search_services/00930000005t000000/)
There is also help to add the service if you don't have it.

If you got to the options in the search pullout>

[image: Screen shot1]
you can access the foders to index and other settings along with pause/resume/delete.

[image: screen shot2]

This from ESRI Help dialog (local)

Reviewing and setting your indexing options
You will need to manage the search properties for ArcGIS in the Indexing/Search Options dialog box.

This is where you can establish the set of folders, GIS connections and ArcGIS Server Search Services to search against. In addition, you can specify when and how often your search index is maintained for ArcGIS.

Building a search index is important so that your search results are fast and accurate. Using default settings will typically serve most users very well. However, you can use this dialog box to modify certain settings. For example:

To identify which folders and connections to index 
To set how often the search index is updated for new items 
To say how frequently you want to re-create the item index 
You can also manually control immediate indexing to update, pause, or re-index your ArcGIS contents.

Open the Index/Search Options dialog box by clicking the icon on the ArcGIS Search window.

In the Index/Search Options dialog box, you can review and set the folders and other ArcGIS connections that you want to index for searching. You can review the current connections in the Register Folders and Server Connections box. Use the Add and Remove buttons to manage this list of connections. These are used to establish connections to a number of workspace folders, geodatabases, toolboxes, GIS servers, and other resources.

Here is a list of connections you can manage for ArcGIS search:
Folder Connections  These are any additional workspace folders to which you have established a connection. You'll see their contents listed under each folder.
Personal geodatabases  Used to organize datasets in a file geodatabase.
Toolboxes  This node is used to organize and access geoprocessing tools.
Interoperability Connections  Used to access a number of special data formats in the optional Data Interoperability extension product. This is used to access Safe Software's FME product for GIS data interoperability. 
Database Server Connections  Used to connect as the administrator to geodatabases that are stored and managed in SQL Server Express.
Learn more about administrator tasks for ArcSDE geodatabases

Database Connections  Used to make user connections to ArcSDE geodatabases in Oracle, SQL Server, SQL Server Express, IBM DB2, Informix, and PostGreSQL.
GIS Server Connections  Used to make connections to ArcGIS servers, ArcIMS servers, and a number of OGC WMS and WFS services.
On the Search tab, you can review and set ArcGIS Search Services in the Register Enterprise Search Services box. Use the Add and Remove buttons to manage the search service list of connections.

Copyright © 1995-2010 ESRI, Inc. All rights reserved.